# Is it possible to achieve non-linear storage of data in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, anonymity

I've recently built a simple survey with a competition element. To enter the competition, the user was required to enter their email address, under the promise of anonymity.

In an effort to anonymize the data, the emails were stored in a separate table, with no foreign keys linking to survey data.

However, with a little knowledge, you can see it's quite easy to merely line up the two result sets and correlate the owner of the survey data. Everybody also opted in, which makes this task even easier. MySQL, even without timestamps and auto-increment columns maintains the inserted order.

So it got me to wondering, is there a clever way of preventing this? Some method of randomising the emails table on insert?

Obviously I know this could probably be done with a App-side callback, but I was looking for something more elegant on the MySQL side.